# An Akbulut cork with a simple equation?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry, 4-manifolds

Is there an Akbulut cork that is diffeomorphic to a complex affine surface that can be given by a simple equation? (for example a surface given by zeros of a low-degree polynomial in $\mathbb C^3$)

Here is a definition of an Akbulut cork: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akbulut_cork note that it is contractible by definition.